# Images in Sandcastle documentation

Tags: documentation, sandcastle

I would really like to add an image into the Sandcastle generated help file for a program.

I've followed the Sandcastle FAQ as closely as I can, and I still can't get the image to show up, although I have managed to get a little image placeholder to show up:
[image: Image Placeholder].

I'm fairly certain that the image path is correct, because when I had an incorrect path, there was an "X" placeholder instead of this one.

I've tried setting the BuildAction for the image to both `Image` (the default) and `Content` (recommended by the Sandcastle FAQ).

Here's what the XML comment looks like: `<img scr="art/Image.png"></img>`

I feel like I've done everything I can to get this to work, and the image still won't show up. If anyone has any other ideas or suggestions, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The art directory needs to be relative to where the help file is generated. Typically the html dir. Like so:

```
[Root]
  \
   [Art]
   |
   [HTML]
   |
   ...
```

In this case:

```
/// <summary>Super Great Method</summary>
/// <remarks>A picture: <br />
/// <img src="../art/myImage.jpg" />
/// </remarks>
```

This discussion might also prove useful to you [MSDN Discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/devdocs/thread/c05c4000-8287-424e-a56f-69fb77dc15ae/)

When adding an image to a conceptual help file, [this method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/devdocs/thread/a8da6db7-f33b-42fa-b1ca-207c54036d0c/) apparently works.

Comment: I have. I've tried many combinations of paths, and anything other than "art/image.jpg" results in the "X" image placeholder, which I assume means the image couldn't be found. "art/image.jpg" is the only path that results in the placeholder mentioned in my question.

Comment: Also, it should be <img *src*> rather than <img scr>, assuming that wasn't just a typo.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I did actually have "scr" in my code. Correcting this changed things. The path that now works is simply "image.jgp"

Comment: lol. Coming back to look at this, I now notice that I mistyped the image extension in my last comment. Not a good day for me, I guess.